# resource cleanup which are only tagged to specific tag

Tags: azure, tags, ps

I am using the below AZ script to delete the tag for a resource. But I want only specific tag needs to be deleted not all the tags that are associated with resource. Example
There is tag name "Business unit" value 101, below are the resource name which are inside this tag:
hrm01vm, hrmvnet, hrmappservice
The above resource are also associated with other tags as well like "Department" & "supportedby"

```
az tag delete --resourceid --yes -y
```

This deletes the entire tags which are associated with the resource. I want only "Businessunit" tags to be deleted. Any command that I need to include?

Parameters in PS.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this using `Remove("<Key>")`. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$a = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP> -Name <FUNCTION_APP>
$a.Tags.Remove("<YOUR_REQUIRED_TAG>")
$a | Set-AzResource -Force
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

*After execution*

[image]